# RuntimeError: Install Flask with the 'async' extra in order to use async views

Tags: python, flask

When I try to run this locally with docker run (locally) I am getting the error below. However, I have already run "pip install "flask[async]" and everything seems to be installed, but I still get the same error! Does anybody have an idea on what's wrong?

```
import asyncio
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import Response
import json
import commacount



app = Flask(__name__)

@app.routes('/')
async def home():
    x = str(request.args.get('x'))
    answer = str(commacount.commaCount(x))
    await asyncio.sleep(2)

    
    
    r = {
        "x": x,
        "answer": answer
    }

    reply = json.dumps(r)

    response = Response(response = reply, status=200, mimetype="application/json")
    
    response.headers['Content-Type']='application/json'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Orgin']='*'

    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000))
```

```
[2021-12-12 04:42:36,711] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1599, in ensure_sync
    return self.async_to_sync(func)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1622, in async_to_sync
    ) from None
RuntimeError: Install Flask with the 'async' extra in order to use async views.
172.17.0.1 - - [12/Dec/2021 04:42:36] "GET /?x=,.., HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Answer (score 17):

install flask with the async extra `pip install flask[async]` as per the [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/async-await/#:%7E:text=Async%20functions%20require%20an%20event,there%2C%20then%20return%20the%20result.)

Comment: it needs quotes: pip install "Flask[async]"

Comment: it needs quotes like that `pip install 'flask[async]'`

Answer (score 14):

In my case, this problem is fixed by install package "asgiref".

```
pip install asgiref
```

Requirement "asgiref" for async views  will not be installed while installing flask. It's considered using sync views by default. So you need to install it yourself.
You can find the error in `[PYTHON_PATH]/Lib/site-packageflask/app.py` Line1618 in verison 2.0.2. This error will raise only import asgiref error.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved with this approach.

Answer (score 8):

i resolve same error with :

```
pip install aioflask
```

so run again the flask with:

```
run flask
```

hope this help the other

Comment: Thanx! Was banging my head for more then 24 hours against the same error :)

Answer (score 7):

Don’t forget the quotations when installing

Pip install "Flask[async]”

Answer (score 4):

First thing you need to use `@app.route` instead of `@app.routes`. You also need to install `aioflask` along with `flask` to overcome this `RuntimeError`

Check below simple example -

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.env = "development"


@app.route('/')
async def home():
    return {"text": "Hello!"}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having same problem.
I tried uninstalling Flask and re-installing Flask with async extra.
Its working fine.

```
pip uninstall flask
pip install flask[async]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install aioflask
```

and instead of

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import Response
```

write `from aioflask import Flask, request, Response`

Answer (score 0):

Routes, error handlers, before request, after request, and teardown functions can all be coroutine functions if Flask is installed with the `async` extra `(pip install flask[async])`. This allows views to be defined with `async` def and use `await`.

for more information Refer the
[Official Docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/async-await/)